# Como alterar escalas de um gráfico multifacetado no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Tenho um gráfico composto por 27 subplots, cada um correspondente a um estado, alguns estados, como SP e RJ possuem valores muito superiores a outros estados e a escala do gráfico fica em intervalos maiores. Há alguma forma de cada subplot ter sua própria escala? Já tentei usar o `coord_cartesian` com o `y_lim`, mas ai acaba cortando o estado de SP e atrapalha a visualização.

Gráfico que está saindo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou utilizando:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
})

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                     "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
  httr::content() %>%
  '[['("results") %>%
  '[['(1) %>%
  '[['("arquivo") %>%
  '[['("url")

dados <- utils::read.csv2(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1")
dados$data <- lubridate::as_date(dados$data)

rm(url)

dados %>% 
  mutate(variacaoCasosNovos = c(rep(NA, 7), diff(casosNovos, 7)),
         variacaoCasosNovos = ifelse(is.nan(variacaoCasosNovos), NA, variacaoCasosNovos),
         variacaoCasosNovos = ifelse(is.infinite(variacaoCasosNovos), NA, variacaoCasosNovos)) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-02-29") %>%
  mutate(cor = as.factor(ifelse(variacaoCasosNovos > 0, yes = 1, no = 0))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = variacaoCasosNovos, fill = cor), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Variação") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o argumento `scales` da função `facet_wrap`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
})

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                     "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
  httr::content() %>%
  '[['("results") %>%
  '[['(1) %>%
  '[['("arquivo") %>%
  '[['("url")

dados <- utils::read.csv2(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1")
dados$data <- lubridate::as_date(dados$data)

rm(url)

dados %>% 
  mutate(variacaoCasosNovos = c(rep(NA, 7), diff(casosNovos, 7)),
         variacaoCasosNovos = ifelse(is.nan(variacaoCasosNovos), NA, variacaoCasosNovos),
         variacaoCasosNovos = ifelse(is.infinite(variacaoCasosNovos), NA, variacaoCasosNovos)) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-02-29") %>%
  mutate(cor = as.factor(ifelse(variacaoCasosNovos > 0, yes = 1, no = 0))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = variacaoCasosNovos, fill = cor), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Variação") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>